# Save plot and text to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, reportlab

I'm generating a couple plots using pyplot and I'd like to save them as a PDF with some additional text information. Currently, I'm storing the plots as a PDF, storing the text information as a separate PDF using reportlab, and then merging the two pdfs using PyPDF2. Ideally, I'd be able to save the plots and the the text in one PDF at once. Is that possible?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
matches1.plot(x='time', y='qty', legend=False, ax=ax1)
matches2.plot(x='time', y='size', legend=False, ax=ax2)
plt.tight_layout()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.savefig('plot.pdf')

packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
y = 400
can.drawString(60, y, "Total 1: ")
can.drawString(60, y-15, "Total 2: ")
can.drawString(60, y-30, "Total 3: ")
can.drawString(60, y-45, "Total 4: ")
can.save()

packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
page = new_pdf.getPage(0)

output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)
outputStream = open("text.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

file1 = PdfFileReader(open("text.pdf", "rb"))
file2 = PdfFileReader(open("plot.pdf", "rb"))

page = file1.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(file2.getPage(0))

output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)
outputStream = open("output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: It seems the text is only a couple of lines. Why don't you directly place the text in the matplotlib figure to save?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh! I didn't know I could do that. Ill check it out.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm doing `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,10))` then `fig.text(0.5, 0, 'hello')`. I'd like to create some space between the bottom of the last subplot and the text, but the subplots take up the entirety of the figure.

Comment: You can adjust where the subplot beginns using `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)` and choose a number to your liking. Possibly make the figure a bit larger, such that in sum the subplot(s) take as much space as the they would otherwise. Call this after `tight_layout` or do not use `tight_layout` at all. If you experience further problems I would recommend showing the prolematic code in the question, or asking a new question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ya I figured out late last night that the problem was `tight_layout`. Thanks!